# SQL Server - how to update the ID column after inserting new records

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

I need to update a SQL Server table periodically by inserting new records into it.

The table has an `ID` column in the form of `Company0001` through `Company0020` right now.

Let's say I added one record of a new company into the table. I want to fill the ID column with `Company0021` for this new record. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: what is this ?? Are you looking for auto-increment?? if yes then alter table and add constraint auto-increment

Comment: Thanks, but no. I do not want to use identity (which I assume is what you meant by auto-increment) for the ID column. I want to keep the format of 'Companyxxxx' as ID, where the 'xxxx' part keep increasing as I insert new records.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tablename
  ADD CompanyID AS 'Company' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(4)) PERSISTED`

Comment: but before do this `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ADD INDEX (id);
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 00001;`

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest to use an identity column. Identity is a mechanism designed and used for this actual purpose and therefore it would be much better in terms of performance.

Nevertheless, if you insist on IDs on the format 'CompanyXXX' I would suggest to use a varchar column. Then you would add a **trigger** on the insert and update operations. When the trigger runs, it would find out the last 'CompanyXXX' and form the new one. If you need help regarding triggers, you could check [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-Sql-Server).

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to have an autoincrement field, and then concatenate the company name with the ID.

If you don't want to do it with an ID field, do you want it to happen automatically, or are you going to manage it manually?  If automatically, you'll need to write a trigger to intercept the INSERT and change the value there.  Shouldn't be too hard to do.

I'd seriously recommend NOT doing this and going down the autoincrement field path.  It's better.

Answer (score 1):

Add another column to the table to hold an integer value (in this example SNo) and then write query as

```
declare @SNo int

select @SNo=max(SNo)+1 from Table_Name

insert into Table_Namevalues (@SNo,'company'+right('0000'+cast(@SNo as varchar(10)),4))
```

And then see the result

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In case a solution is required as, having only one column with values in desired format you can create a function as:

```
create table table1(id varchar(100));
Go

 create function dbo.fn_GetCompanyIdentity ()
 returns varchar(100)
 as
 begin
 declare @CompanyIdentify varchar(100);

 select @CompanyIdentify =  
         (select 'Company' +          
         right ('00000' + cast (
                               (
                               ( 
                               case when Not exists (select ROW_NUMBER() over( order by (select 1)) from Table1 ) then 1 
                               else (select top 1 ROW_NUMBER() over( order by (select 1)) as currentRownumber from Table1 order by currentRownumber desc) + 1
                               end   
                               ) 
                               )
                               as varchar(4))
                ,4));
return @CompanyIdentify;
end;
go
```

and then use the function in insert statement as :

```
insert into Table1 (id) 
select dbo.fn_GetCompanyIdentity();
Go
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD INDEX (id); ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 00001;`

And then `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CompanyID AS 'Company' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(4)) PERSISTED;`  is better approach

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just create an auto-increment column and then concatenate "**Company**" to this column in another column. And for presentation just select "**Company+autoincrement**" column.